# Python sys.stdout.flush() doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, stdout, sleep

The following code is supposed to print from 1 to 10 with 1 second intervals in between, however it is waiting for 10 seconds before actually printing anything and then it prints it all at once. How can I unbuffer the output?

```
import sys
import time
for count in range(10) :
   sys.stdout.write(str(count))
   sys.stdout.flush()
   time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem

```
import sys
import time
for count in range(10) :
   sys.stdout.write("\b%s" % count)
   sys.stdout.flush()
   time.sleep(.1)
```

Don't know why python is weird like this but apparently it accepted this. Your code should've worked fine but I guess python just didn't like you.

Comment: I use python 3.3 btw so it might be different in other versions. Did more research and found that the argument in print "end="\r"" will clear the buffer so you don't need to import sys and if you loop whatever you printed it will replace whatever you just printed.

This gives the output a really cool look

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.7, 3.2, and 3.3 all don't allow keyword arguments in your write call.  Is that the proper code?  The print function of course allows the end keyword and shouldn't be confused with write.  Write does not add a newline character.

Removing 'end' keyword argument and testing shows the code works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response... That was a mistake... even without the end="" the code still pauses before printing everything at once

Comment: I'm completely and utterly unable to reproduce the problem.  Can you narrow it down to a specific python version by testing others?  What OS?

Comment: Mac OSX with python 3.2.3. It just doesnt unbuffer

Comment: Try adding the -u flag to python.