# sys.stdout.flush() not working properly with python and electronjs

Tags: python, io, electron, flush, sys

I'm building an electronjs python application and I'm using the pythonshell module. The electron application is supposed to log any messages my python script prints to the console, but rather than printing each message when it's supposed to be printed it waits until the script has finished executing and then prints everything. I've tried using `sys.stdout.write("message")` and then `sys.stdout.flush()`, but it still **doesn't work**.

The question I'm linking has a similar problem that I do, but the answer that worked for them didn't work for me on the electron application. It's flushing properly on the python backend, the frontend is what's causing the problem.

Similar question: [Python sys.stdout.flush() doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755686/python-sys-stdout-flush-doesnt-work)

Comment: stdout may be line buffered, i.e. it will actually be output when there is an end of line. Does your messages contain an end of line? Else try running your program with `python -u`

Comment: @xhienne is there a way I can call the -u option in my script?

Answer (score -1):

`file.flush()` does not necessarily write the file’s data to disk!. you need to Use `flush()` followed by `os.fsync(fd)` to ensure this behavior.

see below:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
os.fsync(sys.stdout.fileno())
```

**`os.fsync(fd)` documentation from python docs**

> Force write of file with file descriptor `fd` to disk. On Unix, this
> calls the native `fsync()` function; on Windows, the `MS _commit()`
> function.
>
> If you’re starting with a Python file object f, first do `f.flush()`,
> and then do `os.fsync(f.fileno())`, to ensure that all internal buffers
> associated with f are written to disk.

Comment: I tried the following -
`print("Test")
sys.stdout.flush()
os.fsync(sys.stdout.fileno())
print("Test2")
sys.stdout.flush()
os.fsync(sys.stdout.fileno())
print("Test3")
sys.stdout.flush()
os.fsync(sys.stdout.fileno())`
and the js script that calls this python script is supposed to change an element on the HTML to whatever's printed, but rather than changing it to each of the different print statements it immediately skips to the last one. When I add a time.sleep() or run any function between the prints, the program gets to it and stops executing.

Comment: @Avi, have you tried to run my code above?. this shall solve the problem

Comment: I did, I described my error in the comment above (I edited it). sorry if the formatting is bad, I'm new to this

Comment: I tried running the code and the program stopped executing after the os.fsync line