# How to detach a child_process in JavaScript from the main script?

Tags: javascript, python, child-process

I want to have something like a timer program in python running as a child process, so that the python script is printing something every second which is then printed out by the javascript program. I tried something like this:

```
    var python = require('child_process').spawn("path to python.exe",
    ["path to python-program.exe"],
    {
        detached: true
    });
    python.unref();
    python.stdout.on('data', (data) => {console.log(data.toString());});
```

The python code looks something like this:

```
import time, sys

for x in range(10):
    print("x")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

But the javascript program just returns 1 and then after 10 seconds 2 3 ... 9 (every number in a new line) at once.
What I want is, that the javascript program returns the appropriate number every second.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755686/python-sys-stdout-flush-doesnt-work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python sys.stdout.flush() doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755686/python-sys-stdout-flush-doesnt-work)